# change data source for sql server database for any computer wpf c#

Tags: connection-string, datasource, sqldatasource, xamlparseexception

I think my question is probably amateur but i don't know about it & can't find any answer about it .
I Create a program in [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) using [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)
It ran success on my PC , but when install it on the other PCs , it return [xamlparse](/questions/tagged/xamlparse) error & i think its about my connection string.my database is [sqlserver](/questions/tagged/sqlserver) ver. 12.
it's my[connectionstring](/questions/tagged/connectionstring)

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;
```

i think it's about [datasource](/questions/tagged/datasource)

please help me

thx

Comment: In the database, "User" and "Password" are the same ????

Comment: @Alan392 no they're different